# Let $f,g: V \rightarrow W$ be linear operators. Prove that $r(f + g) \leq r(f) + f(g)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $f,g: V \rightarrow W$ be linear operators.
Prove that $r(f + g) \leq r(f) + f(g)$

Note: *r* = *rank*

My idea was to use matrix representation and to prove that the rank of matrix C ($C= F+G$) can't be bigger than the sum of $r(F) + r(G)$,but to use that idea I must prove that $r(f) = r(g)$ which I don't have an idea how to do.
Other idea was to prove that $(f+g)(v) = f(v) + g(v)$ but also with no luck.

Comment: You have a theorem that says $\ r(A+V)=r(A)+r(V)-r(A\cap{V})$

Comment: This question has been asked here many times before and you should do a search.

Comment: Any linear operator can be represented by a matrix, so the question reduces to one concerning matrices.

Comment: Note the ranks of $f $ and $g $ don't need to be equal and similarly you will not necessarily get the equality in the expression.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\operatorname{im}(f+g)\subseteq \operatorname{im}f+\operatorname{im}g$